# What does "morality" and "General welfare in a democratic society" mean in the UDHR?

Tags: human-rights

[The Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/universal-declaration-of-human-rights) (UDHR) permits restriction on human rights based on these reasons (Article 29):

> In the exercise of his rights and freedoms, everyone shall be subject only to such limitations as are determined by law solely for the purpose of securing due recognition and respect for the rights and freedoms of others and of meeting the just requirements of morality, public order and the general welfare in a democratic society.

What do "morality" and "general welfare in a democratic society" mean in this context ?

Comment: [Legal definition of morality](https://dictionary.lawyerment.com/topic/morality/). Obviously, cultural practices do determine what is moral.

Comment: I think it is intended to be "the just requirements of [{morality}, {public order} and {the general welfare}] in a democratic society" rather than "the just requirements of [{morality}, {public order} and {the general welfare in a democratic society}]". In other words, all three requirements apply in a democratic society, not just the last one.

Answer (score 5):

What it means is "if a democracy bans pornography or protests on a busy intersection, that's OK. If a dictatorship bans criticism, even peaceful criticism, that's not OK."

- The first factor is that the ban comes from a democratic government, accountable to the citizens in the next election if the citizens think the government was excessive.
- The second factor is that the ban has one of the enumerated causes, and not just whim of the government.

Documents like this are not meant to be read like a national administrative procedure. They are political declarations of intent and principle. Read about the [Helsinki Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Accords), and the [Helsinki Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Helsinki_Group) this triggered in the USSR to hold the Communist government to their own promises.

Comment: > The second factor is that the ban has one of the enumerated causes, and not just whim of the government.  what are the ennumerated causes you are talking about ? @o.m.

Comment: also how broadly is this clause interpreted ? @o.m. ? your answer seems to give the impression that they can restrict those rights very broadly as long as it's democratically done and for public values

Comment: @Fizz, you should put that into an answer, rather than a series of comments.

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant, "morality, public order, and general welfare."

Comment: after some thinking I think my main question really is weather are all the rights in the declaration are restrictable under those grounds in article 29 ?

Comment: because I think some rights not all  would clearly lose their point if subject to public morals and democratic processes

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant, the declaration envisions a balancing process. As the proverb goes, the right to swing a fist ends at the nose of your fellow man. Article 29 sets out how balancing must be done, especially in conjunction with Article 30.

Comment: i think article 30 seems to be about destruction of rights rather than limitation (since many other human rights instruments contain both terms seperately in interpretation clauses like this) the major concern nevertheless is still that even the limitation of some rights in the declaration would harm their very nature if subject to grounds such as morals and democratic welfare. such as right to be free from torture and cruel treatment.

Comment: But then if the general public is against human right principle (esp women's rights and minority's rights), that would make this part contradictory because the society is democratic, but it is against powerless individuals--which is a violation of human rights.

Comment: @FaitoDayo, consider how long Switzerland denied women the right to vote. The UDHR was not meant to overturn that immediately, even if Article 21 mentions it. The international process was one of gradual reform, not revolution.

Comment: @o.m. but then what is the difference between the entire society being bad (a democracy), and just the ruling elites being bad (a dictatorship) then? This statement is just so biased that it looks like just exists to provide an excuse for America to invade any country it wants.

Comment: @FaitoDayo, look at the history of reform in the Soviet Union. First the dictatorship agreed to these principles, then dissidents claimed them, then reform gradually happened.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a bit of [interesting, maybe] history, some of the wording appears to have been initially (1947) proposed for article 4 by Cuba (which was not communist then)

> The right to choose and profess freely his religion without any restriction other than that imposed by respect for morality and public order.

This was apparently based on the wording of some Latin American constitutions like that of Colombia [1886, art 53]. Cuba's own constitution had something similar at art 35, but I'm not sure when that was adopted.

Later on (in 1948, I think)

> Mr. Loutfi (Egypt) submitted the following text for article 2, paragraph 2, which
> his delegation had drafted in consultation with the delegations of France and the
> United Kingdom:
>
> > “In the exercise of all the rights and freedoms enumerated in this Declaration, everyone
> > shall be subject only to such limitations as are necessary to secure due recognition and
> > respect for the rights of others and to the requirements of morality, of general welfare and of
> > public order in a democratic society.”

There were some objections, but e.g. the argument for this specific enumeration was that

> Mr. Wilson (United Kingdom) saw no valid reason why the three expressions
> should not be retained. In that connexion, he remarked that the terms “peace”,
> “order” and “good government” were to be found together in several federal
> Constitutions and expressing the same idea.

Three was a bit of discussion what words were best in each language, singe "general welfare" did not translate well to French *ad litteram*, so

> Mr. Ordonneau (France) stated that the English expression “general welfare”
> was untranslatable and had very little meaning in French. It was in order to solve the
> translation difficulty that the French delegation had added “la morale” and “l’ordre
> publique” to the expression “bien-être général”, so as to cover everything that was
> contained in the English idea of “general welfare”.

The Soviet side wasn't too happy with this formulation:

> Mr. Pavlov (Union of Soviet Socialist Republics) emphasized that it was the
> laws of States that fixed the limits for the exercise of human rights and freedoms. He
> suggested, therefore, that the following phrase should be added to the text proposed
> by the Egyptian representative: “in accordance with the just requirements of the
> democratic State”.

Some Latin American countries preferred something else:

> Mr. Fontaina (Uruguay) proposed to be guided by article 28 of the Declaration
> of Human Rights adopted by the Inter-American Conference at Bogotá, according
> to which the exercise of human rights was subject only to such limitations as were
> necessary in order to respect the rights of others, the security of all and the just
> requirements of the democratic State.

In the end, this was put to a vote

> The USSR proposal was rejected by 11 votes to 4, with 1 abstention.
>
> The Uruguayan proposal was rejected by 6 votes to 5, with 5 abstentions.
>
> The text proposed by the Egyptian delegation for paragraph 2 of article 2 of the Declaration was adopted by 8 votes to 1, with 7 abstentions.
>
> [...]
>
> The basic objection to the USSR amendment was that if the phrase “and also the
> corresponding requirements of the democratic State” were adopted, the impression
> would be created that the State was higher than morality, public order and general
> welfare and had absolute rights which were not conditioned by the requirements of
> the latter.

New Zealand objected to a longer enumeration than just "general welfare", saying that "public order" was often invoked by non-democratic states, but seemingly that did not carry enough weight.

> although the New Zealand delegation no doubt interpreted the phrase
> “general welfare” in the widest sense, other delegations had expressed the view that it was open to a somewhat narrower and materialistic interpretation. [...]
> Mr. Aikman (New Zealand) [then] withdrew his amendment (A/C.3/267) to delete the words “morality, public order and the” from the text of paragraph 2.

So that was kind it. The text was moved around several times, it was at one point [E/CN.4/148/Add.1] in article 27. At some point

> it had been understood that all reservations and limitations
> in respect of human rights would be contained in article 27

rather than spread them around to caveats on individual articles. (France said on record they'd vote against caveats added piecemeal to other articles.)

I think they introduced more articles then, which pushed it to 29. In fact, at one point it was article 30, they then deleted one.

All quotes from the travaux préparatoires as collected in the Cambridge University Press 3-volume set (2013). (The UN is supposed to have these online, but their links are broken ATM.)

Comment: the above answer seems to point a very broad picture of what would be allowed by this clause. in the sense that the claim seems to be that any restriction is permissable as long as it is democratically elected and/or for public morals.  is this true ?

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant, you can't think of such an international *declaration* the same way you think of national *law*, or even specific international treaties (e.g. CITES).

Comment: @o.m. I'm not sure what you mean. as in isn't the only difference that this isn't binding ?

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant: o.m. probably means that given its brevity, a declaration like UDHR cannot go into details on the balancing. The fact that the caveats in that article could be too broadly interpreted was noticed by others during the drafting too, incl. Australia and the Netherlands representative. But such are the limitations of this class of texts.

Comment: still is the nature of the declaration such that those caveats *could* be interpreted broadly ?

Comment: For example, when Lebanon tried to add more details [to that article], the US objected that "it had already been agreed that the declaration should
contain no implementation clauses. By its reference to national laws the Lebanese amendment had the effect of changing the declaration into a covenant."

Comment: my concern is that article 29 holds the declaration back from being effective because it seems to have too broad uses of the 3 permited restrictions. I don't mean it in a legal sense but more in the "moral weight" sense since that is the purpose of a declaration

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant, a very specific declaration would never be agreed internationally because most countries would find *some* detail that is objectionable to them. A vague declaration can be passed and then develop political momentum (or not, as it may be). Follow the news reports of the UN climate conferences. The delegations hammer out a compromise most can live with, which will be too little, too late, but also better than nothing.

Comment: that's interesting. I thought declarations would be easier to agree on than conventions